# extracting tar files split over multiple dvd's

Tags: dvd, tar

If I have a bziped tar file split over multiple dvd's what's the best way of extracting it without creating a lot of intermediate files? I don't want to first copy all the archive parts to an intermediate disk.

so far the best I can come up with is

terminal 1:

```
mkfifo temppipe1
mkfifo temppipe2
...
mkfifo temppipen
cat temppipe* | bunzip2 |tar -xvf -
```

terminal 2:

```
dd if=archive.tar.bz_part1 of=temppipe1
....
dd if=archive.tar.bz_partn of=temppipen
```

This works, allowing me to change the dvd after each dvd but strikes me as potentially creating a lot of named pipes, and potentially error prone. One typo in terminal 2 and tar is going to quit leaving no option but to start again.  It's also essential to create enough names pipes at the beginning

Anyone got any better ideas?

Comment: You should look at the `--multi-volume` option - One of `tar`'s specialties is splitting an archive across multiple devices sequentially.

Comment: Unfortunately, use of `-M` precludes the use of compression on all versions of tar (big down side), doesn't help at all extracting existing split archives, and has the an issue of portability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a single pipe, and keep a writer open on it so it doesn't close until you are done.

terminal 1:

```
mkfifo temppipe
tar xvfj temppipe
```

terminal 2:

```
cat > temppipe
```

We won't have `cat` write anything to the pipe, but it's presence will keep the pipe open while we run the `dd` commands.

terminal 3:

```
dd if=archive.tar.bz_part1 of=temppipe # and so on
```

Then go back to terminal 2 and hit Control-D.  `cat` will send the final end of file and tar will complete.

Comment: This looks very unix. I have a question though, I am now backing up things using BD 50G discs. I wonder if this will blow up the memory?

Comment: No, memory usage will be constant. Only a limited amount of information can be sitting in the pipe waiting to be read. If `dd` tries to write data faster than `tar` can read it, it will block until `tar` catches up.

Comment: Do you mean it is extracted on the fly as I pipe in the data? Also, I guess `cat archive > temppipe` also works, right?

Comment: Yes, it will be extracted on the fly. And `cat` should work as well as `dd`.